# what does here string function mean

Tags: c++, c++11

```
string ans="";
int x=0,u=1,v=2,y=0;
ans+=string(u-x,'R');
ans+=string(v-y,'U');
```

Here what does string function actually store in `ans` variable

Comment: See the second constructor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: do you know what a constructor is?

Comment: yeah it is used to initialize the object .....

Comment: The page is full of confusing stuff, but the important part is: *"Constructs the string with `count` copies of character `ch`. "*

Comment: @avanish From the code shown, I presume `using namespace std;` or `using std::string` is being used. If so, `string(u-x,'R')` is not a function named string. It is creating a temporary `std::string` object using the constructor that matches the arguments `ux-` and `'R'`. That temporary string is then used as the operand for `ans`'s `operator+=` operator.

Comment: Thank you so much **@HolyBlackCat**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string ans="";
```

After this line `ans` is just `""`.

```
int x=0,u=1,v=2,y=0;
ans+=string(u-x,'R');
```

`string(u-x, 'R')` is equivalent to `string(1 - 0, 'R')` so that constructs a string with 1 copy of `'R'` and then appends that to `ans` so now `ans == "R"`.

`string(v-y, 'U')` is equivalent to `string(2 - 0, 'U')` so you end up with `"RUU"` as the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
ans+=string(u-x,'R');
```

`string(u-x,'R')` is calling a [constructor of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

> ```
> basic_string( size_type count,    
>               CharT ch,
>               const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```
>
> Constructs the string with count copies of character ch.

Further, there is a [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) that appends one string to another.

Putting things together and simplifying the code a bit we get

```
std::string ans;                    // ans == ""
auto countR = 1;
auto countU = 2;
ans += std::string(countR,'R');     // ans += "R"  -> ans == "R"
ans += std::string(countU,'U');     // ans += "UU" -> ans == "RUU"
```

Answer (score 0):

RUU.

The one of the constructors of string takes two arguments string (size_t n, char c); which construct the string instance with n times of c.

Comment: What's *"RUU"*?